# populating Moustache.js template

Tags: javascript, json, mustache, quickbase

I am currently working with a QuickBase database trying to make a custom report using moustache.js, When I was looking into moustach.js I noticed you needed to have your data in JSON format so I used (http://pastie.org/9364908#16) to get my data into JSON which then comes out like (http://pastie.org/9364674#18)

My question is when I make the template for this, does it need to be all contained in the page that the call to get the json data is? I have looked at examples of mustache templates, but all I can find is it being used with data supplied right then made in JSON format, but my data I need is being supplied when I make the call so how would I go about setting that up.?

Comment: the data in a var is the same be it hard-coded or siphoned in via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

When working with mustache js templates (or js templates in general), you do not need to have the template be in the same location as the data being returned from the ajax call. However, you will need to have the data stored in a var that is within scope of the render function of the template. I am assuming you wish to ajax in a set of data, parse it to JSON, then at some point render that JSON data to the DOM. So to answer your questions:

1) Does the template need to be contained in the page that the JSON data is?
 Not necessarily, but you will need to be able to access both parts from one locations (ie, you would ajax in both the template and the data, then put it together. Alternatively, you could store the template in the DOM as a script [recommended way unless you are using AMD], and then render the template when your ajax call is complete).

The main thing to note is you will need to have a reference to both your template and your data in the same scope.

2) Setting up the template / data ?

This can be done by using the ajax success callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

So on success, you can have the function call render on your template, or just set a locally scoped variable with the data and handle the template rendering after.

3) render the template normally

```
var template = $('#template').html(), //script tage with id="template" from your dom
    data = jsonData, //saved somewhere in a local scoped var .. maybe from an ajax call
    rendered = Mustache.render(template, data),
    target = $("#target"); //where the template renders to

$('#target').html(rendered);
```

4) render the template via $.ajax

```
$.ajax("/api/data", function(data){
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data),
        template = $('#template').html(), //script tage with id="template" from your dom
        rendered = Mustache.render(template, jsonData),
        target = $("#target"); //where the template renders to

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kind of information I was needing!